# docker-compose not live reloading React test suite

Tags: reactjs, docker, docker-compose, livereload, docker-toolbox

I am facing an issue with `npm test` not live reloading when running `docker-compose up --build`.

My current setup is Window 10 Home, running docker toolbox. With `CHOKIDAR_USEPOLLING=true` added to the `.env` file in my project root. Volumes were also mounted according.

I have two services `web` and `tests`, running `npm start` and `npm test` respectively. The `web` service live reload upon changes but not the `tests` service, when adding new test cases.

Testing `npm test` locally, it live reloads just fine upon adding new test cases.

---

docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3'
services:
  web:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.dev
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    volumes:
      - /app/node_modules
      - .:/app
  tests:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.dev
    volumes:
      - /app/node_modules
      - .:/app
    command: ["npm", "test"]
```

---

Dockerfile.dev:

```
FROM node:alpine

WORKDIR '/app'

COPY package.json .
RUN npm install

CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

Answer (score 0):

In your docker-compose.yml, try replacing

```
command: ["npm", "test"]
```

for

```
command: ["npm", "run", "test"]
```